# How to add score to javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, input

I was just wondering how to add score to my JavaScript game as I am unsure thanks :)
I am trying to make a score so if you win it adds a point and after ten goes it stops and shows you your score out of ten.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var textfield1 = document.getElementById("textfield1");
    var input = textfield1.value;
    var input = input.toLowerCase();
    var cpu = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

    if (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3) { 
    } else if (input == "rock") {
      var input = 1;
    } else if (input == "paper") {
      var input = 2;
    } else if (input == "scissors") {
      var input = 3;
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Input!"); 
      return;
    }

    if (input == 1 && cpu == 3) {
      alert("You Win! Rock beats scissors!");
    } else if(input == 2 && cpu == 1) {
      alert("You Win! Paper Over Rock!");
    } else if(input == 3 && cpu == 2) {
      alert("You Win! Scissors Cuts Paper");
    } else if (input == cpu) {
      alert("Its a tie!");
    } else {
      alert("You lose!");
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body align="center">
<img           src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/1bb16c331ba5cc303c0f370e9927c740/tumblr_inline_n2yc8uRLei1r6abro.jpg">
<br><br><br><h1><font size="10pt" face="Verdana" color="red">
Scissors Paper Rock Game!



</h1>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="textfield1">
</input><br>
<input type="button" name="button1" onclick="myFunction()" value="Go"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="myScore"value="0" readonly>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Phv9/

Comment: You're probably gonna have to be more specific about what your problem is. I dont think anybody is going to write the code for you...

Comment: Sounds like a fairly straightforward thing, seeing the amount of code you already have. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Well, I set the score to zero at the start of the function then Once you win I add one but every time it starts the function again it starts at zero again? I have tried to store it in an input, the score, and set a variable to it but it says it's an object not an integer and I don't know what else I can try? @CompuChip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set new variables for score and round.

When `myFunction()` calculates the result, you would add one to the round variable regardless, and one to the score only if you win.

You would then calculate if the round is greater than ten, in which case you'd call a new function to handle the game over.

It might help to draw a flow diagram before jumping into the JavaScript, as that can help mentally visualise code like this.

edit: from your comment above, is sounds like you need to look into global variables.  Declare the variables outside your function, and it won't reset.

Comment: When I set the variable outside the function is says undefined

Comment: How are you declaring it? var score=0;  should work.

Comment: If not, set up a jsfiddle with your code and start a new question with the *specific* question of why it is not working.